# resource: net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml not found - Spring and Hibernate Configuration Errors

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I downloaded a tutorial project in an attempt to get Spring and Hibernate working.  However, after running it on the server I get this message:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml not found`

Here is my project structure:

[image]

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>        
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
    <mapping resource="net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="net.codejava.spring.model">
    <class name="User" table="users">
        <id name="id" column="user_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username" />
        <property name="password" column="password" />
        <property name="email" column="email" />
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://domain:3306/databaseHere"/>
        <property name="username" value="insertUserHere"/>
        <property name="password" value="insertPassHere"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `maven` project so the `User.hbm.xml` should be inside `src/main/resources/` instead of `src/main/java`

When you build a maven project then it compiles are the `.java` files present in `src/main/java` and it will not consider any other files which are present in this directory. So the maven project has a folder structure `src/main/resources` where you can place all your configuration files like `.xml, .properties` etc. So when you build the maven project then it will compile all the java files from `src/main/resources` and places the `.class` files in classpath and also maven will copy all the resources from `src/main/resources` and places them in classpath. So when you run the application then the configuration files will also available in classpath.

But if you just place the configuration files in `src/main/java` then maven will just ignore them so they will not be available in classpath.

But if the project you are working on is a simple java project instead of maven project then the code setup mentioned in your question will work without any issues even when you have the configuration files in `src/main/java`. Hope this explanation helps.

To make sure the maven project is build properly you can verify by opening the directory `target/classes/` and then the path to your configuration files.

So, to sum up all this information, here's what you need to do:

Creat a package structure in `/src/main/resources` that mimics the one in `/src/main/java` - that is, create the `net.codejava.spring.model` package in `/src/main/resources` and place `User.hbm.xml` in there.  After running a Maven `clean package` (or some other build goal) command, the `User.hbm.xml` file will be in it's correct location (which is not shown in the picture below) - `/target/SpringMvcHibernateXML-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml`.

Ultimately, after building in Maven, the project should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Gotcha.  In my `hibernate.config.xml` I have `<mapping resource="net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml"/>` - what would the resource attribute become now that `User.hbm.xml` is in `src/main/resources/`?

Comment: @Tylerlee12, no you misunderstood. I will update my question with further explanation, please check.

Comment: Thank you for explaing further, that does make a lot of sense.  However, even after moving `User.hbm.xml` to `/src/main/resources` I am still receiving the `nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml not found` error.  What changes do I need to make to resolve this issue?

Comment: you have to build the maven project, it seems you just placed the file and running the program. Building the project copies the files properly to classpath. Added one more line to my answer for understanding.

Comment: You were right, I wasn't doing that.  However, even after running Maven `clean package` and running using the embedded Tomcat 7 server in Spring Tool Suite I still receive the same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: please learn maven and know how to build the maven project, also confirm if you have the files in `target/classes` directory. Now coming to tomcat part, the tomcat will look for the files under `WEB-INF/classes` directory for `.class` and `.xml` files, please check if they exist. I suggest you to learn basic web-application and maven examples before jumping into this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64679/discussion-between-tylerlee12-and-chaitanya).